# My flexbox items wont display horizontaly?

Tags: css, flexbox

Been trying to solve this weird problem I have for some time now.

My flexbox items wont display **horizontally**?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="subSection contact">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="avatar" src="img/man.png">
            <p>Hello</p>
            <p>IS IT ME YOUR LOOKING FOR</p>
        <img class="avatar" src="img/man.png">
            <p>Hello</p>
            <p>IS IT ME YOUR LOOKING FOR</p>
        <img class="avatar" src="img/man.png">
            <p>Hello</p>
            <p>IS IT ME YOUR LOOKING FOR</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.contact {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You only have a single direct child (flex item) of the flex parent, so there is only 1 item to display horizontally. To get multiple things to display horizontally, the flex parent needs multiple direct children. Looking at the structure, I presume this is what you're going for?

```css
.contact {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="subSection contact">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="avatar" src="img/man.png">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>IS IT ME YOUR LOOKING FOR</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="avatar" src="img/man.png">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>IS IT ME YOUR LOOKING FOR</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="avatar" src="img/man.png">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>IS IT ME YOUR LOOKING FOR</p>
  </div>
</div>
```